# How to use papaparse unparse?

Tags: javascript, csv, papaparse

I was helped here to get this code, but now I need to see how to actually go back to CSV. I have the my code and the sample output of running the script. I really hope that I can get this working. I am using the csv file on my website using WP All Import and it uploads the data but there is a lot of stuff I dont need from the csv file. I will create a cron job to have it run every night so I dont have to do it manually.

js file:

```
papa.parse(file, {
  worker: true,
  header: true,
  transformHeader: true,
  step: function(result) {
    let data = result.data;
    data = data.filter(d => d["Mill Description"].includes('adidas') || d["Mill Description"].includes('adidaChampions'));
  },
  complete: function(result, csv) {
    console.log("parsing complete read: ", result, csv); // Nothing is passed to here yet.
  }
});
```

Output:

```
[{
      "Item Number": "B12704533",
      "GTIN Number": "190311332942",
      "Mill Code": "04",
      "Mill Description": "adidas Golf",
      "Style Number": "A262",
      "Mill Style Number": "TWA262S8",
      "Style Name": "AD LADS MICRO STRIPE POLO",
      "Color Code": "53",
      "Color Description": "ROYAL",
      "Size Code": "3",
      "Size Description": "S",
      "Unit Weight": ".7258",
      "Cost": "0",
      "CC": "0",
      "CD": "0",
      "FO": "0",
      "KC": "0",
      "MA": "0",
      "PH": "0",
      "TD": "0",
      "CN": "0",
      "WA": "0",
      "GD": "316",
      "Total Inventory": "316"
    }]
    [{
      "Item Number": "B12704534",
      "GTIN Number": "190311332966",
      "Mill Code": "04",
      "Mill Description": "adidas Golf",
      "Style Number": "A262",
      "Mill Style Number": "TWA262S8",
      "Style Name": "AD LADS MICRO STRIPE POLO",
      "Color Code": "53",
      "Color Description": "ROYAL",
      "Size Code": "4",
      "Size Description": "M",
      "Unit Weight": ".7717",
      "Cost": "0",
      "CC": "0",
      "CD": "0",
      "FO": "0",
      "KC": "0",
      "MA": "0",
      "PH": "0",
      "TD": "1",
      "CN": "0",
      "WA": "0",
      "GD": "540",
      "Total Inventory": "541"
    }]
```

Comment: Well `Papa.unparse(csv)` in `complete` should do.

Comment: So I was able to get the file output, I did the unparsing in the step function and used a writestream to write to a file BUT my headers are added in the columns. My question then becomes how do I get those to not be added?

Comment: If your question has changed, then you can [edit] it to reflect what it really is.